# How to simplify or factor an expression of non commuting variables

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, simplify, simplification

so this question is most likely very simple and I have seen similar questions on here but none which quite seem to work for me. I am quite the amateur with Mathematica as I never really have much cause to use it so please do not assume much technical knowledge on my part. My problem is fairly simple, I am trying to simplify six expressions which involve two generators x, y that most certainly do not commute. In fact, yx=x^2y. What I would like to get is something of the form (x+...)(y+...)(...) or the like, but whenever I use Mathematica (I have been using the NCAlgebra package) I can't seem to make it work. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you've been attempting so far? It makes it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Well I haven't exactly gotten very far. I have never had any use for Mathematica before, and so I am learning the ropes as I go. So far I have just been trying to factorise or simplify something like x^3+x**y**x using the NCSimplify[] and Factor[] commands.

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version of [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) you can use `NCStrongCollect` and `NCCollect` to produce something like:

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`
expr = x^3 + x ** y ** x
NCStrongCollect[expr, {x, y}]
```

which results in

```
x ** (x + y) ** x
```

or

```
NCCollect[expr, {x, y}, ByTotalDegree -> True]
```

which in this case produces the same result.

There are other "simplification" tools as well, such as `NCSimplifyRational`. Check out the documentation for details.